# Can I leave Moscow Airport while in transit?

Tags: transit, russia, moscow, armenian-citizens

I am traveling to Armenia via Moscow from New York. I have an Armenian passport, which doesn't require a visa to enter Russia. Can I go out to the city while on a 6-hour layover? And how will I get back to the transit area when I am back?

Comment: What airport it is?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can exit the transit area by following the signs for the exit and clearing passport control.

To get back to the transit area, just follow the same path as all departing passengers.

Comment: so I go outside to the arrivals part? And I don't go through the check-in process I only go to the security check part to enter the gate?

Comment: @LolaMunch Correct

Comment: do you by chance know what i could do in Moscow while I'm there?

Comment: @LolaMunch No, sorry, never been there for more than a few hours

Comment: @LolaMunch, I think you can ask a separate question on what to do in Moscow in 6-hours layover (it also depends on whether it is day or night, etc), but generally I think that you will have only time to visit Red Square or any other specific destination. Assume more than an hour to travel from airport to Moscow center, the same time back, and add some safety margin.